# why getting parsing error on building jmeter reports by using jenkins?

Tags: jenkins-plugins

Console Output

> Started by user anonymous Building in workspace C:\Program
>   Files\Jenkins\jobs\Load Test Report\workspace Performance: Percentage
>   of errors greater or equal than 0% sets the build as unstable
>   Performance: Percentage of errors greater or equal than 0% sets the
>   build as failure
>
> Performance: Recording JMeter reports '**/*.jtl' Performance: Parsing
>   JMeter report file C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Load Test
>   Report\builds\2014-06-19_12-30-24\performance-reports\JMeter\dum3.jtl
>   Performance: Failed to parse C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Load Test
>   Report\builds\2014-06-19_12-30-24\performance-reports\JMeter\dum3.jtl:
>   XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
>   Finished: SUCCESS

I change `jmeter.properties` file to give you `jtl` file in `XML` format. Even am getting a same error ? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable blazemeter JMeter plugin if you have one.
This plugin at current state clears sampler results from output jtl and leaves only not valid xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <testResults version="1.2">
```